# Run time optimisation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, optimization, language-theory, interpreted-language

Do the main Javascript interpreters have any built in optimisation at all? I'm thinking of very simple cases like

```
while(i < array.length) { ... }
```

Comment: I don't understand what your code sample has to do with optimization...

Comment: I'm asking if a Javascript interpreter will optimise it for me

Comment: I removed the "general" part of the question since people are voting to close for some strange reason.

Answer (score 0):

your code can be optimize, if that's what you're asking.

```
var ln = array.length; // save length into local variable to reduce scope
while(ln--) { ... }  // only one value is evaluated in while statement
```

Comment: He's asking for optimizations performed by the implementation, not by the programmer.